# How to model Entity1---(1,1)---Relation---(1,3)---Entity2 to a table?

Tags: entity-relationship

I want to convert given ER diagram with (min, max) notation to tables and im unsure of what the primary key of the "trainieren"-relation is.

If the Relation R is between A and B and:

- **one** to **one** -> the primary key is the primary key of either A or B
- **one** to **many** -> the primary key is the primary key of the entity that takes part multiple times in the relation
- **many** to **many** -> the primary key is the primary key of A and B

I'd interpret (0,1) and (1,1) as one and (1,3) and (1,*) as many, therefore 
my solution would be (primary keys in strong text) trainieren: {[**Trainer.AkkrNr**, Teams.Land]}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, we try to use only one or many cardinality indicators, since those map easily to table structure. Most data modelers would do the same as you did in discarding the upper limit to simplify the model.

If you want to enforce that limit, there are a few ways to implement it:

- Use your structure and a trigger on insert/update to count how many trainers the given team has, and throw an error if it exceeds 3.
- You could add a position column to the primary key of `trainieren` and a constraint to limit it to values 1, 2 and 3. However, that imposes an ordering that wasn't part of the conceptual model.
- Change `trainieren` to `(Teams.Land PK, Trainer1.AkkrNr, Trainer2.AkkrNr, Trainer3.AkkrNr)`. Trainer2 and Trainer3 would need to be nullable, and this design loses the constraint that each trainer belongs to only one team. You could fix that with a trigger. Yuck.

Since there's no ideal way to implement an upper bound on the relationship cardinality, most data modelers would follow the same approach as you did, and leave it to the database client (usually the application logic) to enforce that limit.